# How to query childs in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

So here is my collection
[image]

And I need to get the records with age 23, I tried this:

> $results = $table->find(array('author_details.age' => 23));

But it doesn't work, I'm new to mongoDB, and the documentation is bad!

Comment: How does it not work? Did you try iterating the cursor? Also can you show us a mongo console output that screen shot makes it look like you have a field labelled 0 with a element named author_details.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the document with ID `ObjectId("5226e8bcd874593c1400002a")` in your collection, `author_details.age` does not correspond to a property. `author_details` is not a top-level field; rather, it's nested under a top-level `0` field in the document. I have a feeling that the following query would work:

`$results = $table->find(array('0.author_details.age' => 23));`

I doubt that you intended to create a field named `0` in your document, so I'd suggest debugging the code used to insert this document, so you can properly create `author_details` as a top-level field.

> But it doesn't work, I'm new to mongoDB, and the documentation is bad!

If you're referring to the documentation on [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/), please consider sharing *constructive* feedback in the [DOCS bug tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS) or submitting a pull request with some proposed changes in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/mongodb/docs). Issues with the PHP driver documentation can be reported in the [PHP project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP).